# How to get my passwords out of keychain access (and Firefox) from my CCC backup without a Mac?

Tags: backup, password, keychain, firefox, carbon-copy-cloner

My MacBook Pro (running 10.11.6) has a swollen battery, so I shut it down promptly and am sending it in for service.  I have an up-to-date backup (a bootable backup) made with CarbonCopyCloner.  The servicing of the Mac will take a while (maybe a week or so).

In the meantime, a lot of my passwords are unknown to me.  They're mostly auto-generated fully random passwords, saved in either Keychain Access or in Firefox's password-saving feature (or sometimes both).  Obviously I know my login password and the passwords to unlock my keychains (though I often just use the default login keychain), but I don't know most of the other passwords.

Since I do have email access through other devices, I *could* reset various passwords.  But that would be a lot of hassle, and then when I get my Mac back I would have to update the keychains and Firefox.

I have other computers available running Linux (Ubuntu) and Windows (both 7 and 10) to which I can connect my CarbonCopyCloner backup.  I also have an older MacBook Pro from 2010 that I almost never turn on; I think it's running Mac OS Lion (10.7) but it might be Maverick (10.9?).  I'd rather not use that one if I don't have to.

**How can I get my passwords out of the keychain(s) and Firefox data from within my backup?**

<sub>(For completeness, I actually do still have my laptop with the swollen battery since they're sending me a box in a couple days to use for shipping it.  But I'd *really* rather not turn it on given the swollen battery and potential for damage, plus I'm curious about this question for its own sake.)</sub>

Comment: Firefox passwords can be synced by firefox if you sign in to mozilla - but obviously needs to be done before you stop using the Mac (All my passwords are in 1password for the scenario of the question - originally synced via dropbox now using their own server)

Comment: @mmmmmm thanks, I might end up turning it on tomorrow just to transfer the data to an encrypted password database of some sort.  Probably KeePassXC, which looks like the best cross-platform open source password manager, [according to a detailed review](https://alternativeto.net/software/keepassxc/reviews/).

Answer (score 1):

## Keychain Access via Keysafe

For Keychain Access, I wrote [Keysafe](https://miln.eu/keysafe/) to be able to read and export from Keychain files – without requiring an Apple device:

> Keysafe reads and decrypts Apple Keychain files. Use Keysafe to securely access your passwords and credentials without a Mac.
>
> ...
>
> Keysafe can read encrypted passwords and credentials from a Keychain file. To view encrypted information, the Keychain’s password is required. Keysafe does not cirmuvent the security of the Keychain file.